# Dual monitors - second monitor black, but connected

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, wayland

I have a dual monitor set up with desktop computer in Wayland, Ubuntu 22.04. One is connected to dGPU and should run at 165hz, the other -  to iGPU at 60hz.

Using BIOS settings, booting with iGPU as primary has both monitors working, but desktop fps is at 60hz. Booting dGPU as primary runs desktop at 165hz, but shows a black screen on iGPU monitor, but it is still detected and connected (back light is on and is shown in xrandr).

Running Xorg does not have this issue, it has others - very poor gaming performance.

I am doing it this way, since Nvidia never fixed an issue with high idle power consumption of 10 series GPUs when more than 1 display is connected.

---

Hardware:

- CPU: i7 7700k
- dGPU: Nvidia GTX 1080ti (driver version 535)
- iGPU: Intel HD 630
- Monitor 1 (dGPU): Asrock 165hz over DP
- Monitor 2 (iGPU): LG 60hz over DVI

Software:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04
- Display manager: Wayland
- Desktop environment: Gnome

Comment: Have you installed nvidia drivers?

Comment: yes, I should have mentioned it. Thanks for the reminder!